# ASP.NET forms authentication cookie

Tags: discussion, authentication

StackOverflow appears to not use asp.net forms authentication cookies anymore (see: https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/08/a-few-speed-improvements).

So - my question is - how is stackoverflow keeping users logged in? I know that asp.net supports cookieless sessions - but I thought this was implemented by placing the forms ticket identifier in the URL (which doesn't seem to be the case with the site).

At any rate, I think knowing how this was implemented could be beneficial for a few of the sites I manage.

Comment: Belongs on SO?  It's meta, but it's also not.

Comment: Maybe, but I expect if it were asked there without some wording changes it would likely get closed or migrated here.  So when if there's some doubt I tend to leave questions alone.  If it doesn't get any response here he can always ask it again himself on the other site.

Comment: Pesto/Joel: yeah - I wavered as to where the best place for this question to go. I did fear that it would be closed/migrated if on SO - so I thought better to ask here first. If nothing happens to it - I will ask on the main site.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a `user` cookie with 3 values stored in it. I suspect that when the user is authenticated through OpenId, the SO backend creates a ticket (much like typical forms authentication) and the name of the ticket is stored in this cookie instead.

For meta, the cookie is named `somuser` and is different because meta.stackoverflow.com has access to the cookies from the stackoverflow.com domain, so to differentiate them you need a unique name.

#### Reason:

Typical forms authentication cookie value:

```
DAD01018945EA4DEC22AD1F73BB5F99A1F4D579877B3B17D1A582B00C66D79DF7650EB133AB91B474A9D2BFB3A8A92453992D67894C615F828295956292929244054E3B4B8B94B4B08A59F1C1577B18EF5E65A2F6007E9962469D8073BE3C3505D241BBB5E69CCD91052960900EEB6F6B4598E39DF0E1B5D45C5429C00B8D5B
```

New cookie value:

```
t=W/jwldc2k0m5&s=LEowkckwhkyC&p=[2|2]
```

Much shorter, which means every request is smaller in size.

Comment: interesting - so you think they implemented their own forms module to work in this manner and override the default behavior?

Comment: That's my assumption, only the SO developers would be able to verify that for sure